# Saving text to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use this code it works fine but not the way I want. I don't want this `IBAction` to take me to the second View Controller I just want it to save the text to the second View Controller.

```
- (IBAction)passtexttovc2:(id)sender {
    ViewController2 *vc2 =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    vc2.stringfromteztfield1= self.Actionforbutton.text;
    [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:NO];
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on object oriented programming. Multiple instances of the same class are not the same object.

Answer (score -1):

Remove

```
[self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:NO];
```

Only present it when you wanted to.

Comment: i did remove this line of code before, but it doesn't work! is there anything i can write instead,,,

Answer (score -1):

The `presentViewController` method is unnecessary here. You do not need to 'present' the view controller here per se.

Comment: i did remove this line of code before, but it doesn't work! is there anything i can write instead,,,

Answer (score -1):

When you say save, i think of core data: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html